# rails can not connect local database without internet

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database

HI guy,

I have a rails app and config database like below. If i have set up internet it works well, but without internet it will not connect to local database.

```
development:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: merpro_development
  pool: 10
  username: root
  password: xxxxx
  host: localhost
```

Can someone give me help to resolve the issue? thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "without internet"?  What OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally found that it's caused by FF, in FF file menu there is a work offline check, cancel it, everything will be ok.

Answer (score 1):

How are you testing this exactly?  When you disable your internet connection, can you ping 127.0.0.1 or localhost?

Alternatively, you can try connecting via the local file socket, remove the host line and setup the following

```
  socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

The path might be elsewhere such as /tmp/mysql.sock

```
  lsof -p `pidof mysqld` | grep sock
```

That command should help you find the socket.

Comment: @arex1337 just now i have tested many times and finally found that it's browser related. after disconnecting internet ie and chrome can work well to connect db. but FF can not. and i changed localhost to 127.0.0.1 in FF, it doesn't access. so i think it's FF issue. thank u.

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess, does it work if you change localhost to 127.0.0.1?

Comment: let me try to disconnect internet.

Comment: are you on a UNIX system ?if yes have a look that your loopback interface is setup properly (ifconfig) . if not , try to set not only the host but also the socket of your mysqld in database.yml .

Comment: I'm not very skilled in Windows system , but i will suppose there is a loopback interface in windows too . otherwise , try to use a socket , you have to explicit it in database.yml and configure your mysqld to open a socket . here a simple tutorial (googled) http://www.devside.net/guides/windows/mysql